# Record method calls including parameters such that they can be executed after program has executed

Tags: java

I am creating an automated test framework.  At present in order to best find any issues I have introduced randomness into the tests, such that a test will generate random data and try multiple paths.  However this has lead to a problem, I am no longer able to easily re-execute failed tests.

In order to proceed I need to implement a way to store the actions of the test, including their parameters.  With the way I have implemented the framework all of the "work" is handled by one class, thus if I was able to record the methods invoked with parameters in this class then I would have a full record of actions executed in the script.

From this list of methods though I need an easy way to re-execute these method calls, preferably with as little manual work as possible.

Sorry if this has been asked before but I wasn't able to find anything to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be possible to record and reproduce the actions by some complex reflection or aspect-oriented programming, it's probably easier to just make the process repeatable by dealing with the randomness a bit differently.

Precisely how the current version of `java.util.Random` determines the seed if it's not specified, I'm not sure.  In 1.4.2, it was documented as being

```
 public Random() { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }
```

But if instead of letting it default to something based on current time and out of your control, you explicitly set the seed to something known (possibly `System.currentTimeMillis()`), and record the seed that was used, then you can easily replay with the same seed and get the same sequence of "random" numbers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this Don.  I ended up implementing your approach, but for some reason it doesn't always produce the same output.  I am going to investigate that further.  I've ended up implementing another solution using java refection and writing to a file.